# Can't save .png ext in database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm sorry I can't upload png image to database using laravel but jpg uploaded successfully, validation don't work if I deleted the validation give me the below error, thanks in advances.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'businessimg' doesn't have a default value

```
public function storefiles(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:9048',
]);  
    $addfiles= new Files();
    $addfiles->appo_id = $request->input('Appoid');
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
       $file = $request->file('file');
       $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      Image::make($file)->save(public_path('Admin/BusinessCards/'.$filename));
       $addfiles->businessimg = $filename;
  }
   $addfiles->save(); 
   return redirect()->back(); 
 }
```

My HTML:

```
<form class=""  action="{{url('storefiles')}}"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">      
        <input type="hidden" name="Appoid" value="{{$addfiles->id}}">
      <label for="File">File :</label>
    <input type="File" name="file">
   <input class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
   </form>
```

Comment: Not sure what this line is for as it does not appear to be being used `$allowedfileExtension=['jpeg','jpg','png','svg'];`

Comment: Thank you, but give me an error, SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'businessimg' doesn't have a default value

Comment: If you knew the error message why didn't you put that into the question in the first place?

Comment: The error comes when I delete the validations

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
$file->save(public_path('Admin/BusinessCards/'.$filename));
```

Instead of it

```
Image::make($file)->save(public_path('Admin/BusinessCards/'.$filename));
```

Comment: Sorry but didn't save .png ext